# when we need to convert binary to hexadecimal in real life

Tags: c++, binary, hex

I am a student and studying about binary and hexadecimal.I want to know why we need to convert binary number to hexadecimal number.What is its use in real life?

Comment: The goal is cosmetic /  convenience, it is just to simplify the writing : 4 binary digits (bits) can be written uniquely as 1 hexadecimal digit. 0000 <-> 0;, 0001 <-> 1; 0010 <-> 2 .... 1110 <-> E;1111 <-> F . It is just for convenience. Note that we often use groups of 8 bits (often called bytes), which translate to 2 hexadecimal digits. 16 bits translate to 4 hexadecimal digits, and so on.

Comment: A subset of the use of either binary or hexadecimal numbers in real life, I'd imagine.  (Converting between these two is trivial, as @Pac0 points out.)

Comment: When working with bits, using decimal numbers is a real hassle. Since the C++14 standard we can have binary integer literals, but they can be kind of long and easy to get a bit wrong. That makes it easier to use e.g. hexadecimal notation, since each digit corresponds to exactly four binary digits.

Comment: To give a more "real (programmer's) life" -> when we want to look at / edit a  binary file, we use hexadecimal digits, because otherwise it would be a nightmare to edit each bit among the hundreds / thousands / millions of bits.  Example : https://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/

Comment: Remember : at the end these are just numbers, on an *abstract scale*, it **doesn't matter** if the number is **written** in base 2, base 16, base 10, base64

Comment: Any specific reason this is tagged C++?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are 10 different kinds of people, those who understand binary, those who don't, and those who realize this joke is in trinary.

People are better at handling fewer symbols of more types.  Computers are designed to handle 2 symbols (0 and 1) and lots of them.

Hex is a useful format, because it uses fewer symbols and more types, but it is easy to convert to/from binary.  So when you want to examine binary, or input it, hex is highly useful for humans.

It is usually better than octal (base 8) because each hex digit is 4 bits, and binary data is usually arranged in clumps of powers of 2 due to how our computer bit-addressing works.  So you'll have 8 bit bytes, 16 byte words, 32 byte double words and 64 byte quad words; this comes out to 2, 4, 8 and 16 hex digits.

As each octal digit is 3 bits, and 3 doesn't divide any power of 2, this doesn't work out as neatly for common binary bit clumps we manipulate.

This answer assumes "real life" is "working with computers".  From programming down to picking colors on a web page, you'll use hex while doing this.

Comment: The number of symbols people find easy to handle is limited, and the sweet spot seems to be around 10. Imagine thinking in base 256: "the address of this variable is `0x008b4eac`" seems human readable. However, "the address of this variable is `␀‹N¬`" - only 4 symbols, but not human-readable.

Comment: @anatolyg actually we seem pretty confortable with 24 symbols (alphabet). Chinese script has thousands, but it takes them a long time to learn a sufficient subset of those.

Answer (score 2):

If you are stuck using a pre-c++14 compiler you won't have binary literals available except as an extension. Even then since 4 binary digits is always equivalent to 1 hex digit it is often easier to get long constants right by using hex instead of binary. (imagine for instance writing the 33 binary digits needed to get 0x100000000, it would be easy to miss a 0 or insert an extra).